# Plot a Gaussian Distribution over a Histogram

Tags: python, dataframe, distribution, gaussian, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a Gaussian Distribution over a histogram for a project.

I have read a csv file and produced a pandas data frame.

I have produced the histogram, and I have tried a few methods to fit a distribution, however I always end up with a straight line formed at the bottom of my histogram. I think it may have something to do with the column I am trying to fit over is an Float64 but I'm not sure how to change that.

So far I have...

```
x=df1['rating']
plt.figure(figsize(10,10))
plt.hist(x, bins=20,color='c',edgecolor='k', alpha=0.65, linewidth=2)
plt.axvline(x.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2,label="mean")
plt.axvline(x.median(),color='r',linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2)
```

[Rating Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2)

Comment: Please post sample data

Comment: Hi, please try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "...and I have tried a few methods..." Which?

Comment: @Chris @mikuszefski `data={'Name':['Tom', 'Joe', 'Chris', 'Jane'],'Age':[20,21,19,18]}` `df=pd.DataFrame(data)`
```df```

Comment: ```Data2= df['Age'] mu,std=norm.fit(Data2) xmin,xmax=plt.xlim()
x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,71)
p=norm.pdf(x,mu,std)
plt.plot(x,p,'k',linewidth=4)```

Comment: When I do the above method on my original data, I just get a straight line at the bottom of my histogram. I think the issue is that the Data2=df['Age'] line is returning a float64, but I will be honst, I don't know what that means or how to fix it.